# Pass more fields from billing.phtml to my java web service?

Tags: java, php, web-services, zend-framework, magento

Im using the Magento 1.6 and I use a web service to process some of the fields I pass along. I've added two fields to the zend's `billing.phtml` form and I want to pass that along also to the web service.

I see that I can access the built in fields but I wish to add my custom ones as well. What is the best way to do this?

The solution I'm seeing right now is that when I select and input the field (its is a drop down box and a input menu), using `AJAX`, I post it to a `PHP` form and it stores it as a session variable but I see this more as a bandage fix than anything else.

Comment: Also Ive searched for extensions that do this but I dont see any that especifically allow me to add custom fields.

Comment: Surprised that noone has any idea for this. Is there some detail I am missing to communicate?